# How do I reassign the ordering of symbols in a polynomial expression?

Tags: formatting, polynomials, symbols, sorting, order

I have a big polynomial expression, like this:

```
a E1^(-1 + α) g I1^(-1 + κ) α κ + 
 c E1^(-1 + γ)
   E2^δ g I1^(-1 + κ) γ κ + 
 a E1^(-1 + α) I1^(-1 + μ) I2^ν j α μ + 
 c E1^(-1 + γ) E2^δ I1^(-1 + μ)
   I2^ν j γ μ + 
 d E1^(-1 + ϵ) I1^(-1 + ξ) k ϵ ξ + 
 E1^(-1 + η) E2^θ f I1^(-1 + ξ) k η ξ + 
 d E1^(-1 + ϵ) I1^(-1 + σ)
   I2^τ m ϵ σ + 
 E1^(-1 + η) E2^θ f I1^(-1 + σ)
   I2^τ m η σ
```

where my variables are `{E1,I1,E2,I2}`. I just want change the presentation of the expression, i.e., all the constants first and then the variables. For example, for the fist term of the expression above: `a*g*α*κE1^(-1 + α)*I1^(-1 + κ)`. 
Is this possible? How can i do this?

Comment: Rename your variables so that `a`, `g`, `α`, `κ` are `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, and `a4`., etc. *Mathematica* automatically sorts expressions behind the scenes, and there is nothing you can do about it apart from writing somewhat complicated functions that change the displayed form of your equation. a comes before E, so those are likely to come first.